# Flask logger and config with APScheduler

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler

I am using BackgroundScheduler from apscheduler.schedulers.background in my flask application to schedule background jobs.

I want to use flask logger and config in these background jobs but I see they can be used only after the application is initialized. Is there a way I can use flask logging and config file in the following use case? (One way is to use python logger)

```
app = Flask(__name__)

#BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start()
#Add jobs to the scheduler
# Shut down the scheduler when exiting the app
atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Thanks